# PHP add Line Break after each 5th result

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a page break after every five instances of the word "hello!"

I could obviously go on forever with  the "||" method I'm using below, but that seems to be bad coding practice. What would be a better way to write this?

```
              $count = 0;
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                echo "hello! "
                $count += 1;
                if ($count == 5 || $count == 10 || $count == 15 || $count == 20) {echo "<br>";}
```

Comment: You can do % 5 or collect all of Db results in an array, then array_chunk in 5 and then implode

Answer (score 2):

Use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

It checks if there is a remainder when dividing this by 5 (if it is divisible by 5):

```
if ($count % 5 == 0)
```